# Graphical Bug on recent 16.04 update, missing text/icons etc

Tags: unity, graphics, icons

Since about a week ago, after going through a routine software upgrade for Ubuntu 16.04, I have this weird graphics issue where certain text or icons will be blacked out. This makes it very hard to use several applications, since often huge chunks of text will be missing on buttons.

[image: An example of what the bug looks like]

Any idea what could be causing this or how to fix it?

I'm using an Nvidia graphics card with the open-source driver, which unfortunately is required since I dual-boot into Windows with secure boot enabled.

---

Update (output upon running sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -f):

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Get:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]  
Get:4 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [809 kB]
Get:5 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [738 kB]
Get:6 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [318 kB]
Get:7 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [226 kB]
Get:8 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [643 kB]
Get:9 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en [259 kB]
Get:10 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [246 kB]
Ign:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Get:12 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [331 kB]
Get:13 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,964 B]
Get:14 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages [6,744 B]
Get:15 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages [6,740 B]
Get:16 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,324 B]
Get:17 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,100 B]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]    
Hit:19 https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable InRelease     
Hit:20 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                    
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [67.7 kB]
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [68.0 kB]
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [107 kB]
Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [140 kB]
Fetched 4,303 kB in 2s (1,887 kB/s)                                   
AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors.
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_AU) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_AU) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:

$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bbswitch-dkms dkms lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 libjansson4 libllvm5.0 libvdpau1 libxnvctrl0 mesa-vdpau-drivers nvidia-prime nvidia-settings vdpau-driver-all xserver-xorg-legacy
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  base-files snapd
2 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 14.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,167 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 base-files amd64 9.4ubuntu4.7 [65.9 kB]
Get:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 snapd amd64 2.33.1ubuntu2 [14.1 MB]
Fetched 14.2 MB in 0s (36.5 MB/s)
(Reading database ... 227661 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../base-files_9.4ubuntu4.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking base-files (9.4ubuntu4.7) over (9.4ubuntu4.6) ...
Processing triggers for cracklib-runtime (2.9.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
Processing triggers for plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (0.9.2-3ubuntu13.5) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.11) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-130-generic
Setting up base-files (9.4ubuntu4.7) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/issue ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/issue.net ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/lsb-release ...
Processing triggers for plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (0.9.2-3ubuntu13.5) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.11) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-130-generic
(Reading database ... 227661 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../snapd_2.33.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking snapd (2.33.1ubuntu2) over (2.32.9) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up snapd (2.33.1ubuntu2) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh ...
snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.

$ uname -a
Linux MU00141536L 4.4.0-130-generic #156-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 14 08:53:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ apt-cache policy ubuntu-desktop
ubuntu-desktop:
Installed: 1.361.1
Candidate: 1.361.1
Version table:
 *** 1.361.1 500
    500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 1.361 500
    500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This looks more like a UI theme configuration issue. Can you please log into a guest user session or create and log into a new and pristine (temporary) user account to check if the same issue reoccurs there? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks! I do get the same issue on a guest account.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I updated the question with that information. The problem hasn't been resolved after I restarted to be sure.

Comment: That was all I got from the commands. I've added the output of uname -a and apt-cache to the question.

Comment: I ran `sudo debsums -cs` and only had issues with some python3 packages, which I re-installed any now I get no errors when I run the same command.

Comment: Can you please reboot and check if the UI issues persist?

Comment: @DavidFoerster rebooted and the issue is still there.

Comment: Alright, then I'm out of my wits here unfortunately.